# how to conditionally retrieve elements?

Tags: matlab

I am not Matlab user but have to deal with it for now. I could not find out how to:

```
[row,col]=matrix1[matrix1==100];
```

How to exclude row=5?

Comment: Post an example with a small matrix to show what you want

Answer (score 1):

The following procedure should illustrate the steps you need to take (even though a more efficient solution may be possible):

```
%// Generate some numbers:
matrix1 = randi(4,5);
%// Find the indices of the elements you are looking for:
VALUE_TO_FIND = 3;
[row,col] = find(matrix1==VALUE_TO_FIND);
%// To exclude a certain row, simply "delete" the elements pointing there:
ROW_TO_IGNORE = 4;
col(row==ROW_TO_IGNORE)=[]; %//it is important that this line comes first
row(row==ROW_TO_IGNORE)=[];
```

If you want to ignore a certain column, switch the order of the last two lines (and change the condition in the parentheses accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as post processing:

```
sel = row~= 5;
row = row(sel);
col = col(sell);
```